# How to create a Linuxterminal with a Pythonclass in Eclipse

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, pydev, gksudo

I'm trying to figure out how to open a terminal in linux, when I'm going to run my Pythoncode in Eclipse.

So I got the idea to use `os.popen("gksu -S command,"w")`. But for this way I need to enter my password. Can I add my password anywhere in the script or into the `os.open` command?

Thanks for the help.
:)

Here is my Code:

```
import os
class Init(object):

   def prepareVM(self):
       os.popen("gksu -S virtualbox,"w")

   prepareVM(super)
```

Comment: Can you give more details on what you want? I.e.: why gksu virtualbox and not just xterm?

Comment: what is the advantage of using xterm?

Comment: Well, xterm is the terminal on Linux, whereas virtualbox is a new virtualized hardware (and you said you wanted to create a linux terminal).

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Virtualbox was just an example to start an application with root priv. by an own created linux terminal. I used gsku to give in the password.

Comment: Ok, so, doesn't just subprocess.Popen(['xterm', '-e', 'other', 'args']) work for you? Why would you need gksu?